# Is there a way to prevent expiration of an Azure DevOps Personal Access Token (PAT)?

Tags: security, automation, permissions, azure-devops, access-token

**Context**: Within an Azure DevOps user's Personal Access Token (PAT) settings, there is the ability to scope the Organization the token has access to and set an Expiration date up to one year.

**Question**: Is there a way in settings/options to prevent expiration or automate token regeneration? Supplementary question (opinion), is that a bad idea?

Comment: @Robert They are clearly distinct questions.

Comment: Sorry, For me it looked more like a question that was saved multiple times, and meanwhile reworked. In any way I would recommend to shorten the titles. Such long titles are IMHO deterrent.

Comment: @DanielMann The question is if there is a way to prevent expiration or automate renewal. Where is the hangup? Provide advice so it can be asked better.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer The question is fine. Someone else (who has since deleted their comment) was claiming it was a duplicate of other questions you asked. I was pointing out that you asked three distinct questions, all about the same general topic.

Comment: Thanks. Have you configured Azure DevOps releases? I'm trying to achieve keeping builds out in DevOps, but then deploying to internally hosted IIS boxes. There seem to be several ways to do this looking at MS documentation, but it is unclear the security issues associated, and which one is most appropriate for traditional (non-VM, non-containered) hosting. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer There is currently no feature to prevent expiration or automatic renewal. You could submit a uservoice on [DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21).In addition,is the following answer helpful to you ?  If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 4):

Each PAT has a expired date, the default period is 30 days and the maximum period is one year.

If the PAT created at the beginning is 90 day, when it expires, you can choose to change to 180 days or 1 year. But if you start in 1 year and expire soon after one year, you can only add one more token.

In addition ,the following [notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0iEX.png) is sent - a PAT is near expiration.

This is intended to prevent PAT from being leaked to pose a threat to the user's personal information security in its long-term use.

Updating PAT in a timely manner helps protect your information.